# Ignore event handler for S1172 (Remove this unused method parameter)

Tags: c#, sonarqube

The Sonar rule csharpsquid:S1172 (Remove this unused method parameter) is thrown also for event handlers like this:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething()
}
```

Is there a way to have the rule ignore event handlers, since they are auto generated like this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way currently to ignore event handlers, but we have fixed this issue in the upcoming release, so event handlers with the standard signature (2 parameters, the second is `EventArgs` or derived, and returns `void`) will not show up for S1172.

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't it make sense to also check if the first parameter is of type object?

Comment: Yes it would make sense. We found some cases that don't conform strictly to the MSDN suggestions, so we left out that check. We prefer to have false negatives.

Comment: In what version should this be fixed? I've upgraded to C# plugin 4.4 but the issue is still there, and I also couldn't find anything in the release notes.

Comment: This issue is still here

Comment: Can you still reproduce it? Might be worth raising a github issue if so.